# WPF ListView confusing the SelectedItem with equal items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, silverlight

A ListView (or ListBox) with following properties:

```
  <ListView SelectionMode="Single">
     <sys:String>James</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Claude</sys:String>
     <sys:String>Justing</sys:String>
     <sys:String>James</sys:String>
  </ListView>
```

will result in selecting two items simultaneously if I click on "James", even though
I chose SelectionMode="Single". It's even the same behaviour when I use a helper class with
a string-property to display in the ListView. It seems like the ListView is evaluating the Items and selecting those which are Equal() rather than ReferenceEqual(). Is there a way to change this behaviour so that the ListView treats every item individually?

Comment: I'll bet you the cause is not Equal() vs. ReferenceEqual() but rather string interning.

Comment: When I fill the ListView programmatically with like tmpList.Add(new { Diplay = "James" } and bind on the Display-Property, the effect is the same, even though the strings are wrapped in a helper class.

Comment: It's because there is nothing there to make each instance of James unique. You need an ID or something to distinguish between the two.

Comment: This one's ancient, you should not add strings like that, wrap them in ListBoxItems or ListViewItems respectively.

Comment: I lose my bet.  See my answer.  And +1 for this question, because answering it made me learn two new things that I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem really is `Equals()` versus `ReferenceEquals()`.

> It's even the same behaviour when I use a helper class with a string-property to display in the ListView.

Not quite.  You get the same behavior if you use an *anonymous* helper class.

Why doesn't wrapping an anonymous type around the string fix the problem?  As described [here](http://jclaes.blogspot.com/2011/04/anonymous-type-equality-follow-up.html), when you create an anonymous type, the compiler creates a generic `Equals()` method that returns `true` if the objects are of the same (anonymous) type and their properties have the same values.

The solution is to implement a real (non-anonymous) class - it can be as simple as this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
}
```

`Object.Equals()` does a reference comparison, so as long as you don't override it, you'll get the behavior you would expect.

I suspect that the design of the control assumes that you're not going using it to display lists containing two equal items.

As to why it uses `Equals` and not `ReferenceEquals`, I suspect that the underlying design choice has to do with the fact that controls have to be able to display value types. `ReferenceEquals` boxes value types, with the result that `ReferenceEquals(1,1)` returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and elaboration, I was indeed using anonymous types instead of real classes for my tests. Though I don't really understand why there's a need for the ListView to select all items that are equal in value instead of just the item that was clicked on. Are there scenarios in which this behaviour is desired even with SelectionMode=Single being set?

Comment: I suspect that the design of the control assumes that you're not going using it to display lists containing two equal items. As to why it uses `Equals` and not `ReferenceEquals`, I suspect that the underlying design choice has to do with the fact that controls have to be able to display value types.  `ReferenceEquals` boxes value types, with the result that `ReferenceEquals(1,1)` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the desired behavior, you will need to create a helper class that wraps the string type like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name) { Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using it, you can now do the following:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("James"), new Item("John"), new Item("Steve"), new Item("Drew"), new Item("Andy"), new Item("James") };
    list.ItemsSource = _items;
}
```

with the XAML like this:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Single" x:Name="list" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: Why `public Item Self { get { return this; } }`?

Comment: Correct - it is not needed and therefore got removed from the example